# Отображение таблиц в навигаторе MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте, как вы знаете в левом нижнем углу в навигаторе MySQL Workbench всегда присутствует список баз данных, в них таблицы. Я создал четыре таблицы не "мышкой", а вручную, набирая скрипт. Так вот таблицы в списке не отображаются, хотя запросы к ним делать можно. Когда создаю таблицы "мышкой" (клацаю на галочки NOT NULL, PK и т.д.), то отображаются таблицы, как исправить ситуацию?

Comment: А если на 'Tables' нажать ПКМ и выбрать refresh all ?

Comment: Refresh all не дает результатов!